# Navigation Bar Interfering with Divs

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could stop div's from falling under my navigation/information bar when I minimize the screen's width. The information bar is 1200px in height, I just want it to sit on the left side without any disturbance from div's and other code when I decide to minimize the width.

Or better yet, if someone could show me how to shrink the "information bar" in height when the browser is minimizing while the div's fall under it that would be very helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href=o>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Abril+Fatface|Amaranth|Arapey|Armata|Asap+Condensed|Bellefair|Cabin+Condensed|Cormorant+Unicase|Cormorant+Upright|Dancing+Script|EB+Garamond|Economica|Frank+Ruhl+Libre|Great+Vibes|Gruppo|Gudea|Halant|Heebo|Hind+Guntur|IM+Fell+Great+Primer+SC|Italianno|Karla|Kreon|Kristi|Kurale|Molengo|Old+Standard+TT|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Ovo|Parisienne|Pinyon+Script|Poiret+One|Pontano+Sans|Prata|Quattrocento|Rouge+Script|Share|Spectral|Tangerine|Tenali+Ramakrishna|Trirong|Voces|Yantramanav|Yrsa" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Site</h1>
        <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Information</li>
        <li>Wanting</li>
        <li>To</li>
        <li>Stay</li>
        <li>Undisruptive</li>
        <li>To</li>
        <li>Div's</li>
    </ul>
        </nav>

<div>
    <div class=red>
    </div>
    <div class=red>
    </div>
    <div class=red>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    text-align:center;
    font-family
}

h1{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:1em;
    font-size:2em;
}

.menu{
    background-color:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:1200px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;

}

.red{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px){
    .red{

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at something like Bootstrap which provides a CSS framework for responsive layouts?

Comment: I have not yet. Mainly because I want to master CSS before I move onto bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful:

You can change width into "%"

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family
}

h1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.menu {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 25%;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 75%
}

.red {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
.menu {
  width: 35%;
}
.right {
  width: 65%
}
}
```

```html
<h1>Site</h1>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Information</li>
    <li>Wanting</li>
    <li>To</li>
    <li>Stay</li>
    <li>Undisruptive</li>
    <li>To</li>
    <li>Div's</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="right">
  <div class=red>
  </div>
  <div class=red>
  </div>
  <div class=red>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without changing the %?

Comment: In small screens: if you want to get div without resizing, the right div should move below the information div.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, your code is at a very basic level to achieve what you ask for, but I have tried something, hope so that fulfils the requirement.

```
<div class="site-name">
  <h1>Site</h1>
  <div class="hamburger" id="hamClick">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li>Information</li>
    <li>Wanting</li>
    <li>To</li>
    <li>Stay</li>
    <li>Undisruptive</li>
    <li>To</li>
    <li>Div's</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div>
 <div class=red></div>
 <div class=red></div>
 <div class=red></div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
  text-align:center;
}

.site-name {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  background-color:black;
}
.site-name h1{
  color:white;
  font-size:2em;
}

.menu{
  background-color:gray;
  width:200px;
  height:1200px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

.red{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
.hamburger {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: block;
}
.hamburger span:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    height: 0px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu.active {
    height: 150px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .red {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100vw; */
  }
}
```

and a little bit of Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('hamClick').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var collapse = document.getElementById('menu');
  collapse.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Look at the JSFiddle code here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to39t4u8/1/)